# Can a character use her movement to help someone else stand up?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, prone

Standing up takes [half your movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#BeingProne), and you can also [interact with one object for free](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#BeingProne) during your turn. Neither of these things indicate whether or not you can help someone else stand up on your turn. If you can [knock someone prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#ShovingaCreature) or [drop prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#BeingProne), then it makes sense that you would be able to help someone else stand up. Do the rules allow this?